# Starting mongoDB server fails

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed mongodb server on my ubuntu using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-server
```

But I can't start it.
When I try to run the server, it says:

```
masious@ubuntu:/var/log/mongodb$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
mongod: symbol lookup error: mongod: undefined symbol:
_ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitEPKcPKNS_10RE_OptionsE
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have already done to try and fix this? (We wouldn't want to suggest things you've already tried). Have you checked the documentation? (This could be a service you need to start, instead of running the binary directly).

Answer (score 1):

While this is a simple matter of reading the manual, I'm going to post an answer as it may come back again and again as "sys admins" start managing MongoDB without reading the manual:

> The mongodb-org package includes various control scripts, including
>   the init script /etc/init.d/mongod. These scripts are used to stop,
>   start, and restart daemon processes.

...

> Start MongoDB.
>
> Issue the following command to start mongod:
>
> sudo service mongod start

Ref: [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Now obviously you did not install the mongodb-org package. So perhaps the one distributed on Ubuntu repo is different... but again, that goes back to not reading the manual. I won't quote how to install MongoDB as per the manual as I already put the link above anyway.

Comment: But when I try to install mongodb-org, this happens:
`masious@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org`

Comment: Please... READ and FOLLOW the manual... you have to add the source first...